# How to bind formControl value dynamically?

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying ti bind the formControl value on a input element dynamically in a loop.

```
<div *ngFor="let value of values">

<input  attr.formControl="{{value}}" type="text"/>            

</div>
```

This isn't working. The formControl attribute isn't a standart html attribute so I guess there has to be some other way to bind the value.

Usually the formControll is bound like this

```
[formControl]="name"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<div *ngFor="let value of values">

<input [formControlName]="value" type="text"/>            

</div>
```

Comment: No, it's not working. Error: Cannot find control with name: 'value'. Btw, did u give the postfix name behid formControl on purpose or it's just a typo ?

Comment: @user49126 My bad, I edited the comment, check it now. `formControlName` is not a typo, you can check how to create model-driven forms on these links: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management and http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html